# Viewdidload and observe methods for firebase view controller not being called, nothing is printed to console

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, viewdidload

I'm trying to load data from firebase into an array of Company objects, but it's not working. By using print statements, I noticed that `viewDidLoad` method and the `observe` method are not being called. Nothing is printing to the console, except for a bunch of firebase text (i.e. "Firebase automatic screen reporting is enabled...").

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class Information: UIViewController {

var ref:FIRDatabaseReference?
var databaseHandle:FIRDatabaseHandle?
var companiesInformation = [Company]() //holds name, booth, image

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("viewDidLoad was called")

    //Set firebase database reference
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    // Retrieve posts and listen for changes
    databaseHandle = ref?.child("companies").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Code that executes when child is added
        let company: Company = Company()
        company.name = snapshot.value(forKeyPath: "name") as! String
        self.companiesInformation.append(company)
        print("databaseHandle was called")
    })
}
}
```

After downloading Firebase and Firebase real time database using cocoa pods, I added the 2 necessary pieces of Firebase code in my App Delegate and my app runs without errors. I only have 2 yellow warnings as shown below:

[image]

So why isn't the database working and why is nothing printing to the console?

Comment: If you're using the Firebase database, the import should be *import Firebase*. Also, in your delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions func, you need a FIRApp.configure(). If the viewDidLoad method is NOT being called in your viewController class there's an issue elsewhere in the code unrelated to Firebase. You may not need the databaseHandle either - depends on the rest of the code. The error in the question may be because the PodFile is not configured correctly and/or your CocoaPods is out of date - add it to the question so we can take a look. Whew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake. I realized that I was not calling the Information View Controller when I built my app, so the `viewDidLoad` method was not being called, so nothing was printing.